# Can I ask CreateSpace to *not* add a barcode to my cover?

Tags: self-publishing, printing, isbn

I'm about to publish a book via [CreateSpace](https://www.createspace.com/). For graphical reasons, I prefer to add the ISBN barcode myself at the size and position of my choice. How can I set it up on CS so that they don't add a barcode on my cover?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should ask this question to the [CreatSpace community](https://www.createspace.com/en/community/index.jspa).

Besides that, you can [add your own barcode](https://na5.salesforce.com/_ui/selfservice/pkb/PublicKnowledgeSolution/d?orgId=00D300000001Sh9&id=50170000000I1eh&retURL=/sol/public/solutionbrowser.jsp?search=barcode&cid=02n70000000DfLu&orgId=00D300000001Sh9&t=4&ps=1) as the [help](https://admin.createspace.com/Help/Index.jsp) stated.

Comment: Thanks. It seems in fact that barcodes are not added to covers that you make yourself. I guess I'll have to try to make sure.